# Integrate Google Calendar from my account in iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-signin

I use Google Calendar to add events.
I need display these events at special page in iOS application (users should see all events that I have in my Google Calendar).

I read here that iOS app must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth

So, users see "Sign In" button in iOS application.
How can I "sign in" automatically to display events in iOS application? Is it possible?

Comment: have u successfully implemented google calendar in swift app @Kirill

Comment: yes, I've added server side and get data from server

Comment: bro how can i connect u i need help regarding this i m searching for soultion since 1 month

Comment: I wrote a server side: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/dotnet
And I use Alamofire to get data from server

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if my understanding is wrong, if you want to share your calendar events to everyone, you may do the following steps specified in [this support post](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/34580?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). You can set until what extend you want the users can do to your calendar. But if you want to implement sign in refer to [Integrating Google Sign-In into your iOS app](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift#top_of_page).